# What happens when an anti-proton and an electron collide with each other?

Tags: particle-physics

The vice versa case is also of interest (proton and positron). Are both processes actually symmetrical?

Comment: They scatter... what do you mean by symmetrical?

Answer (score 3):

The same kinds of things that happen when an electron collides with a proton.

Electrons (both matter and antimatter) being leptons and (anti-)protons being baryons there is no annihilation issue, so this is primarily an electromagnetic scattering event (with a small admixture of weak scattering which will be just slightly different).

In principle such an experiment should be sensitive to violations of isospin symmetry, but I think that the same data is more readily available in Drell-Yan experiments.

Comment: Why can we use Drell-Yan experiments to get the same data? Isn't that a hadron–hadron scattering event? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drell%E2%80%93Yan_process

Comment: Sorry, that comment was about *"sensitive to violations of isospin symmetry"*. I was trying to think of a use for the reaction you are asking about and comparing the weak amplitudes of $e^+/p$ or $e^-/n$ to get access to isospin violations was all I could come up with. If that is gibberish to you, then just ignore it: the first two sentences contain the answer.